# How to fix the map layer scale size in mapserver(ms4w)

Tags: gis, mapserver

Sample layer map file is:

```
LAYER
        NAME "abc"
        STATUS OFF
        CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
        CONNECTION ""
        DATA ""
        TYPE polygon
        TRANSPARENCY 100        
        MINSCALEDENOM 1
        MAXSCALEDENOM 4000

    METADATA
        "fields"    "layer"
    END
    CLASS
        NAME 'abc'          
        MINSCALEDENOM 1000
        MAXSCALEDENOM 4000
        STYLE
            OUTLINECOLOR 21 58 224
            COLOR 151 219 242   
        END
    END     
END
```

How to fix the map layer scale size of 1:4000 ratio In map file of map script mode in Map Server(ms4w)

can any body help me ?

Answer (score 1):

It is doable but requires a lot of effort to do so.

It is challenging because the scale is the default parameter for WMS getMap operation. The generic WMS getmap operation with a bbox with two coordiantes comes with a width and height as the output parameter. Without knowing what the output width and height will be, it will be hard to simply

The bbox of two pairs of coordinates and the width and height are the parameters decided what is the scale of the output image.

Imagine we have an interest area and a fixed scale at 1:4000.

So in some part of the system we need to get the height and width of the output in a situation like a window in a front end application or a print map extend. we will need to calculate the center point of the area/shape for the output, then recalculate the bbox coordinates based on pixels to the center point in width and height. Then use the new two pairs of coordinates and the height and weight to do the wms getmap request.

In this way the center part is still remain in the middle and the bbox may changed to make sure the scale is fixed as expected.This is complicated at server side using mapserver alone but can be easily managed by using other applications/APIs like OL3,leaflet,ArcGIS Javascript API etc. which has the function to force the output to be in a fixed scale.